# Gnome Terminal Emulator intercepting function keys

Tags: gnome-terminal, i3-wm

I recently switched over to i3, and now I have a wierd problem. If I am using a CLI program that uses F1, F10, or some of my other function keys, the terminal emulator will pop up menus instead of sending the keystroke to the CLI program. This is especially a problem in alsamixer and htop. How do I fix this?

Comment: You can redefine the gnome terminal keyboard shortcuts in preferences.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to redefine the gnome terminal keyboard shortcuts, you can use another terminal emulator,for example good old xterm.

```
xterm -e htop
```

or if you want a larger font for example

```
xterm -fa default -fs 12 -e htop
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Edit` -> `Preferences`, here you'll find the options to disable Alt+letters and F10. Then switch to the `Shortcuts` tab and scroll to the bottom to remove F1's binding for Help (double click on F1 and press Backspace).